# TSQL remove img tag with specific src from HTML

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, replace

I have an html text in my database with many img tags. My goal is remove img tags with specific src

My Input is

```
<div>
    <p>some text goes here <img width="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" /></p>
    <p>some other text goes here <img height="100" src='/upload/remove-me.png' width="200" /></p>    
    <p>some other text goes here <img src="/upload/filename.png" /></p>
</div>
```

I'd like to remove all images where src="/upload/remove-me.png" my output result to be

```
<div>
    <p>some text goes here</p>
    <p>some other text goes here</p>
    <p>some other text goes here <img src="/upload/filename.png" /></p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do it with regex in TSQL?

Comment: tsql does not support regex except in clr functions. I would suggest doing this outside the sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it seems the tags can have their attributes in any order, so we need to loop through the text to take out the img tags one at a time.  Obviously you will want to try this on a backed up version of your data to make sure it is only removing what you want to be removed:

```
declare @HTML table(a nvarchar(max)) 
insert into @HTML
select 
'<div>
    <p>some text goes here <img width="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" /></p>
    <p>some other text goes here <img height="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" width="200" /></p>    
    <p>some other text goes here <img src="/upload/filename.png" /></p>
</div>'


declare @URL nvarchar(50) = 'src="/upload/remove-me.png"'   -- Search for img tags with this text in.
declare @TagStart int = -1
declare @TagEnd int = -1

while @TagStart <> 0
begin
    select @TagStart = patindex('%<img%' + @URL + '%/>%',a)-1       -- Find the start of the first img tag in the text.
            ,@TagEnd = patindex('%/>%'
                                        ,substring(a
                                        ,patindex('%<img%' + @URL + '%/>%',a)
                                        ,999999999
                                        )
                                )+1                                 -- Find the end of the first img tag in the text.
    from @HTML

    update @HTML                -- Update the table to remove just this tag
    set a = (select left(a,@TagStart) + right(a,len(a)-@TagStart-@TagEnd)
            from @HTML
            )

    select @TagStart = patindex('%<img%' + @URL + '%/>%',a)     -- Check if there are any more img tags with the URL to remove.  Will return 0 if there are none.
    from @HTML
end

select a as CleanHTML
from @HTML
```

Comment: Worked exactly as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

XML DML gives more elegant solution. Most probably your main table has HTML field as `(n)varchar(max))` so a temporary table is necessary.

```
declare @HTML table(id int, a xml) 
insert into @HTML
select id, html
from dbo.myTable
/* content of html field
'<div>
    <p>some text goes here <img width="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" /></p>
    <p>some other text goes here <img height="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" width="200" /></p>    
    <p>some other text goes here <img src="/upload/filename.png" /></p>
</div>'
*/
update @html
set a.modify('delete //img[contains(@src,"remove-me")]') --delete nodes and update
from @HTML cross apply a.nodes('div') t(v)

--select * from @html --just to see what happens
update dbo.myTable
set html = h.a
from dbo.myTable t
inner join @html h on t.id = h.id
```

Comment: Very elegant indeed!

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, I love it, but the only downside is that it requires valid xml structure and unfortunately my input text may not always start with <div>, it can just start with plain text without any tags

Comment: This works with plain text as well. Just wrap the field with `div`. Like this `insert into @HTML
select id, '<div>'+html+'</div>'
from dbo.myTable`

Answer (score 0):

If the `img` is constant as a whole (not just the src):

> ```
> <img height="100" src='/upload/remove-me.png' width="200" />
> ```

then you can use a simple `REPLACE`, like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=REPLACE(
  columnname,
  N' <img height="100" src=''/upload/remove-me.png'' width="200" />',
  N''
)
WHERE columnname LIKE N'% <img height="100" src=''/upload/remove-me.png'' width="200" />%'
```

The space before the tag is intended.
If the markup is stored in an `ntext` column, convert to `nvarchar(max)` first, otherwise `REPLACE` will fail.

If this is a task other than a one-off data correction, you should rather include that with your business logic layer.

Comment: This will not work as even the example data given in the question does not have uniform attributes.

Comment: right. If OP could limit it to a set of known permutations, he could do an `UPDATE` each. otherwise, your solution above is clearly better for this task

Comment: Replace is not an option, in my example I've posted different variations I may have. So something generic is required

Answer (score 0):

The following function should do the job. It simply finds the image start and end tags for the targeted image name and then removes the text.

```
ALTER FUNCTION Html_RemoveImageAttributes
(
    @sourceImage        NVARCHAR(100),
    @inputHtml          NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @imageTagStart INT = CHARINDEX('<img ' , @inputHtml, 1);
    DECLARE @imageIndex INT = CHARINDEX(@sourceImage, @inputHtml, @imageTagStart);
    DECLARE @imageTagEnd INT = CHARINDEX('/>' , @inputHtml, @imageTagStart);

    DECLARE @outputHtml NVARCHAR(MAX) = @inputHtml;

    WHILE (@imageIndex > 0) 
    BEGIN

        IF (@imageIndex > @imageTagStart) AND (@imageIndex < @imageTagEnd)
        BEGIN

            -- Remove first occurrence of image.
            SET @outputHtml = REPLACE(@outputHtml, SUBSTRING(@outputHtml, @imageTagStart, @imageTagEnd - @imageTagStart + 2), '');

            SET @imageTagStart  = CHARINDEX('<img ' , @outputHtml);
            SET @imageIndex  = CHARINDEX(@sourceImage, @outputHtml);
            SET @imageTagEnd  = CHARINDEX('/>' , @outputHtml);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            SET @imageTagStart  = CHARINDEX('<img ' , @outputHtml, @imageTagEnd);
            SET @imageIndex  = CHARINDEX(@sourceImage, @outputHtml, @imageTagEnd);
            SET @imageTagEnd  = CHARINDEX('/>' , @outputHtml, @imageTagEnd + 1);

        END

    END


    RETURN @outputHtml

END
```

The following example shows how it can be used:

```
DECLARE @sourceImage NVARCHAR(50) = 'remove-me.png';
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(4000) = N'<div>
    <p>some text goes here <img width="100" src="/upload/remove-me.png" /></p>
    <p>some other text goes here <img height="100" src=''/upload/remove-me.png'' width="200" /></p>    
    <p>some other text goes here <img src="/upload/filename.png" /></p>
</div>';

PRINT dbo.Html_RemoveImageAttributes(@sourceImage, @input);
```